# Vista won't recognize my DVD ROM

Tags: windows-vista, dvd

The problem is simple, when I go to Computer, I don't see my DVD drive, however I can still open/close it. I haven't been using it for couple of months, so I'm not really sure at what point did it stop working.

Sorry that the screenshot isn't in english, basically:

- C: & D: - first and main parititioned HDD
- E: - USB device
- F: G: H: I: - memory card reader
- L: - second HDD

[image]

And one even funnier thing, when I mount an ISO image in Daemon Tools, it also doesn't show up. It just seems that Windows isn't happy with any kind of CD/DVD drive.

I'm using Vista Business x64.

Comment: I suggest to try according to this link http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314060

Comment: Does it show up in the Device Manager? Does it show up in the Disk Manager? (If it doesn't have a drive letter assigned, it's not supposed to show up here.)